# How do you interpret the cross-entropy value?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, neural-networks, interpretation, cross-entropy

In machine learning, cross-entropy is often used while training a neural network.

During my training of my neural network, I track the accuracy and the cross entropy. The accuracy is pretty low, so I know that my network isn't performing well. But what can I say about my model knowing the cross-entropy?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Andrew Ng explains the intuition behind using cross-entropy as a cost function in his [ML Coursera course](https://youtu.be/rtD0RvfBJqQ) under the logistic regression module, specifically [at this point in time](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YUCen9E79YY) with the mathematical expression:

$$\text{Cost}\left(h_\theta(x),y\right)=\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
-\log\left(h_\theta(x)\right) \quad \quad\quad \text{if $y =1$}\\
-\log\left(1 -h_\theta(x)\right) \quad  \;\text{if $y =0$}
\end{array}
\right.
$$

The idea is that with an activation function with values between zero and one (in this case a logistic sigmoid, but clearly applicable to, for instance, a [softmax function](http://cs231n.github.io/linear-classify/#softmax) in CNN, where the final output is a multinomial logistic), the cost in the case of a **true 1 value** ($y=1$), will decrease from infinity to zero as $h_\theta(x)\to1$, because ideally we would like for its to be $1$, predicting exactly the true value, and hence rewarding an activation output that gets close to it; reciprocally, the cost will tend to infinity as the activation function tends to $0$. The opposite is true for $y=0$ with the trick of obtaining the logarithm of $1-h_\theta(x)$, as opposed to $h_\theta(x).$

---

Here is my attempt at showing this graphically, as we limit these two functions between the vertical lines at $0$ and $1$, consistent with the output of a sigmoid function:

[image]

---

This can be summarized in one more succinct expression as:

$$\text{Cost}\left(h_\theta(x),y\right)=-y\log\left(h_\theta(x)\right)-(1-y) \log\left(1 - h_\theta(x)\right).$$

In the case of softmax in CNN, the cross-entropy would similarly be formulated as

$$\text{Cost}=-\sum_j \,t_j\,\log(y_j)$$

where $t_j$ stands for the target value of each class, and $y_j$ the probability assigned to it by the output.

Beyond the intuition, the introduction of cross entropy is meant to make the cost function convex.

Comment: To the beyond intuition part I would also add that cross entropy also emerges from maximum likelihood estimation for logistic regression model

Comment: Is this only for binary case? ..  what about above?

Comment: @BobBurt I included a link to a page explaining the extrapolation to softmax and the cross entropy equations that follow,

Comment: @BobBurt This answer explains the relationship between binary and multinomial cross-entropy. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/260505/machine-learning-should-i-use-a-categorical-cross-entropy-or-binary-cross-entro/260537#260537

Comment: The second cost expression should be: $$\text{Cost}\left(h_\theta(x),y\right)=-y\log\left(h_\theta(x)\right)-(1-y)\log\left(1-h_\theta(x)\right).$$

Comment: @user650654 Thank you. Can you please edit the answer accordingly?